# Strange Segue Behaviour in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue

So I've researched this one for quite a while. I'll try my best to explain it here, because there's not a singular piece of code that I can give since I'm not sure where the culprit is at for this one. Here's the issue: Our app has google maps as the main view. From there you can click a "Share Party" button and it will take you to a page to enter info about the party, which you can then share, or share and invite friends (both do the same thing, the latter just segues you to the invite friends page for that party after creating the party). All is well. However, after a. making a party and then making another party, or b. viewing a party and then making another or c. viewing a pop up (such as an alert controller) and then making a party, the app seems to randomly segue after making it to a view controller that allows you to view party details. And it seems to be proportional to how many times you do those things above, meaning if you did any of the above x times, it will segue to that view controller x times after creating a party. I don't know if it's legal to put our app name on a public post but it is in the apple store, so PM me if you want to try and recreate it to see what I mean.

EDIT: I'm not seeing anything in the debugger to show that anything is amiss as well. Not even a warning or anything.

EDIT 2: More Info:

Initial setup of our MapView and SlideMenu from the login view controller:

```
func createMenuView() {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mapViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MapViewController") as! MapViewController
        let menuViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController") as! MenuViewController

        let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mapViewController)

        menuViewController.mainViewController = nvc

        SlideMenuOptions.leftViewWidth = 210.0
        let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController:nvc, leftMenuViewController: menuViewController)
        slideMenuController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
        slideMenuController.removeLeftGestures()

        let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

        delegate?.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
        delegate?.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Prepare function for the segue to PartyDetailsViewAndEdit (the offending segue), from our MapViewController (which appears after logging in, see above):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "createPartySegue" {
        //let destinationNavController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        //let destination = destinationNavController.topViewController as! EditEventViewController
        let destination = segue.destination as! EditEventViewController
        destination.delegate = self
        destination.location = activeLocation
        destination.locationGMSPlace = searchedPlace
        print("seguing to: EditParty")
    } else if segue.identifier == "RequestPartySegue" {
        let destinationNavController = segue.destination as! SelectFriendsViewController
        destinationNavController.request = true
    } else if segue.identifier == "PartyDetailsAndEditSegue" {

        let vc = segue.destination as! PartyDetailsViewAndEditController
        let marker = sender as! PartyMarker
        mapView.selectedMarker = nil
        vc.partyId = marker.party.partyID!
        print("seguing to: \(marker.party.partyID!)")
        vc.isfromMap = true
        vc.partyData = marker.party.partyToDictionary()
    } else if segue.identifier == "InviteFriendsSegue" {
        let selectFriendsController = segue.destination as! SelectFriendsViewController
        let marker = sender as! PartyMarker
        selectFriendsController.inviteToPartyId = marker.party.partyID!
        selectFriendsController.partyName = marker.party.name
    }
}
```

Then, the other piece, is actually creating the party from the EditPartyViewController. This basically deals with all the backend uploading, and then uses it's delegate (MapViewController), to dismiss the EditPartyViewController and add the party to a pin, which is then added to the map. This function addParty in the MapViewController is:

```
func addParty(_: EditEventViewController, with party : Party, at gmsPlace : GMSPlace?, fromCell: Bool) {
        activeMarker?.map = nil
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: gmsPlace!.coordinate, zoom: 16)
        self.mapView.animate(to: camera)
        let partyMarker = PartyMarker(party: party)
        partyMarker.position = (gmsPlace?.coordinate)!
        partyMarker.setIcon()
        partyMarker.snippet = gmsPlace?.name
        partyMarker.map = self.mapView
        partyMarker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
        self.partyMarkers[party.partyID!] = partyMarker
        if fromCell {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "InviteFriendsSegue", sender: partyMarker)
            self.fromCell = true
        }
```

As far as general segue layout once you get to the mapview, you can either A. View a party, (push segue), or B. Create a party (this used to be a modal segue, with the EditPartyViewController embedded in a NavController, however I was getting a warning about window hierarchy so I changed it to push temporarily, which is what it is now). When Viewing a party, if you have invite permissions, you have push segues to an InviteFriends VC where you can either invite from Facebook Friends, or/and from your contacts. All of these are push segues.

Comment: BTW, have you inspected *all* methods calling `performSegue` with the offending segue id as arg? I'm assuming here your issue comes from a manual segue...

Comment: Hi I'll take a closer look if you want. I was just wondering if you could provide a more clear map of the segue patterns (what segues are possible from what views), as well as whatever code is running when a segue is triggered. Also, the type of segues may be relevant as well, depending on how your views are structured. Hard to say without more info.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for the responses I'll be checking all of this shortly.

Comment: Hi, I have included some additional info in the post. Hopefully this can help. Again, it's hard to identify the exact code that is the culprit here. I've searched pretty thoroughly and the code I provided is the only sensible code that would be causing the issue, but I don't see how. One of my main issues is I came on as a lead dev to this project after our previous dev team was let go, so a lot of the code is quite frankly messy and hard to sift through. It's made debugging these things a nightmare haha.